# How to scrape an html hidden table

Tags: r, xml, rvest

I am trying to scrape some tables from here: https://www.adfg.alaska.gov/index.cfm?adfg=commercialbyareapws.harvestbydistrict However, the tables are not visible until I manually select them from the dropdown (see snapshot below). I need to download a few different tables from 221,222,223,226,227 and 228.

[image]

I need to download these tables using R and save them as data.frames or as Excel files.
Any suggestion on how to go about this?

**UPDATE: Here is the snapshot of the inspect network option.**

[image]

Comment: When you select from the page dropdown the page makes a form POST request to `https://www.adfg.alaska.gov/analytics/saw.dll?ReloadDashboard` - part of that form contains the entry selected from the dropdown. You can try replicating that in order to get each table.

Comment: I get this error when trying: https://www.adfg.alaska.gov/analytics/saw.dll?ReloadDashboard---- `Invalid request. Note that some urls may not be bookmarked or emailed.
Error Codes: IKRU2L4C`

Comment: You would need to try mimicking the entire POST request according to what is shown in the network tab of browser when selecting from dropdown.

Comment: None of the paths found on the network tab take me to the tables, in this case selecting 222 from the dropdown. See snapshot attached above.

Comment: This is the POST https://filebin.net/ojfdpjckv04r5ds7

Comment: I looked up and down but all my id's start with 51 and yours start with 45. Does that number varies from computer to computer? Also, how can you tell that that's the right ID? I am asking because I will need to get 7 tables from that site. And my last question is, once I found the right ID, do I double click on it or put it on the address bar? Please forgive my ignorance about this topic.

Comment: Focus on the actual data points shown (within the td elements). It is quite possible the 45/51 is dynamic. That content overall is dynamically added via JavaScript running on page and isn't just loaded as is.